# FileReader in JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, html, macos, webkit, javascriptcore

I am trying to to read local files using jsc. How can I use File API? Although Safari 9.1 on El Capitan supports HTML5 File API, I get the following error with jsc.

```
$ cat foo.js
var f = new FileReader();
$ alias jsc=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/
$ jsc foo.js
Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FileReader
global code@foo.js:1:23
```